# What does use_locking=True do in TensorFlow optimizers?

Tags: multithreading, locking, tensorflow

Does it only protect against asynchronous updates or does it also cause other access to the variable to wait for the update? I'm using the same model for training and inference at the same time and want to make sure that inference is always done on a consistent model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Passing `use_locking=True` when creating a TensorFlow [optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#optimizers), or a variable [assignment](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.assign) op, causes a lock to be acquired around the relevant updates to the variable. Other optimizers/assignments on the same  variable also created with `use_locking=True` will be serialized.

However, there are **two caveats** that you should bear in mind when using this option:

- Reads to the variables are not performed under the lock, so it is possible to see intermediate states and partially-applied updates. Serializing reads requires additional coordination, such as that provided by `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer`.
- Writes (optimizers/assignments) to the same variable with `use_locking=False` are still possible, and will not acquire the lock. The programmer is responsible for ensuring that these writes do not occur.

Comment: In ps-worker mode, multiple worker's subgraph would update same variable. Such as in ApplyFtrl default use_locking=False, multiple write would handle same memory region, it's a bug or in this case we have to open use_locking?

Comment: @mrry what do you mean when you say "Other optimizers/assignments on the same variable also created with use_locking=True will be serialized", please explain.