# Tensorflow Multithreading: How to Share Variables Across Threads

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, locking, reinforcement-learning

I am working on an a multithreaded implementation of DDPG (Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient) in TensorFlow/Keras **on the CPU**. Multiple worker agents (each with a copy of the environment) are being used to update a global network via worker gradients.

My question is: How do you properly update the global network via its workers and then safely run the updated global network periodically in its own copy of the environment? The intent is that I want to periodically observe/store how the global network performs over time, while the workers continue to learn/update the global network via interacting with their own copy of the environment. According to this [Stackoverflow question regarding locking in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715915/what-does-use-locking-true-do-in-tensorflow-optimizers), "Reads to the variables are not performed under the lock, so it is possible to see intermediate states and partially-applied updates". I would like to avoid the global network being partially updated/mid-update as it interacts with its environments.