# Will using multiple minimizing ops at once work as expected in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, if I do:

```py
loss_one = something
loss_two = somthing_else
train_one = tf.train.AdamOptimzer(0.001).minimize(loss_one)
train_two = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss_two)
sess.run([train_one, train_two])
```

Will that do what's expected? The reason I'm concerned is because I don't exactly know how gradients are accumulated. Are they stored on the optimizers themselves? Or on the variables? If it's the second, I can imagine them interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not. Presumably, both `loss_one` and `loss_two` are a measure of how close the output of your model, let's say `out`, is to what you expected, so they would both be a function of `out` and maybe something else. Both optimizers compute the variable updates from the `out` computed with the values that the variables had before calling `session.run`. So if you apply one update and then the other, the second update would not be really correct, because it has not been computed using the now-updated variables. This may not be a huge issue though, since. A more complicated problem is that, depending on how exactly the optimizer is implemented, if it is something more or less like `variable = variable + update` then it is not deterministic whether that `variable` on the right-hand side of the expression has the original or first-updated value, so you could end adding only one of the updates or both, non-deterministically.

There are several better alternatives:

- Use only one optimizer at a time, so you call `sess.run(train_one)` first and `sess.run(train_two)` later.
- Optimize the (possibly weighted) sum of both losses (`tf.train.AdamOptimzer(0.001).minimize(loss_one + loss_two)`).
- Call [`compute_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients) from the optimizer for each loss value, combine the resulting gradients however you see fit (e.g. adding or averaging the updates) and apply them with [`apply_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#apply_gradients).
- Use [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) to make sure that one optimization step always takes place after the other. However this means that using the second optimizer will always require using the first one (could be work around, maybe with `tf.cond`, but it's more of a hassle).

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'm not concerned about the staleness part, because if I were using GradientDescentOpt, it's the same as adding the losses. But, partial updates are a real problem. For now, I'll do the first (because it's the easiest). The second option won't work for me with ADAM -- one of the reasons I use ADAM is that my losses are very different in scale, and the ratio changes as training goes on. The third option sounds good, although also like a decent amount of work. What about the use_locking option? Do you have experience with that?

Comment: @SamBobel I don't have experience with `use_locking`. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715915/what-does-use-locking-true-do-in-tensorflow-optimizers) (which you may already have seen) I'm not sure whether or not it gives you guarantees in your case. I have added another alternative with `tf.control_dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

the optimizer is mainly  in charge of calculating the gradients(backpropagation), if you give it loss twice(run it two times as you are doing), it will update the gradients twice by performing inference once.not sure why would you do that though

Comment: Well, as an example, two losses with two different learning rates. Or that operate on different var_lists, but with some overlap (that's the real use-case).

Comment: Do you have two models? I am not sure if you can have two losses for one model,especially if the the will affect the model parameters

Comment: It's two sections of a connected model that you want to optimize for different reasons. It's part of an actor-critic setup for reinforcement learning. But the question is just about the nitty-gritty Tensorflow details, because I'm not sure if doing two gradient-calculations at once will interfere with each other.