# how does use_locking in optimizer influence performance

Tags: asynchronous, tensorflow, serialization

I read [What does use_locking=True do in TensorFlow optimizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715915/what-does-use-locking-true-do-in-tensorflow-optimizers), but can not realize  the answer.

I have the following questions:

1. what performance does the `use_locking=True` will impact?   training speed , accurancy or something else? If it depends on the model type, just take the tensorflow official mnist tutorial for example.
2. To be honest, I don't know much about the `lock` concept. so is there a more detailed explanation about the official doc : `use_locking: If True use locks for update operations`
3. Is there some materials for realizing the serialization, asynchronous related concept in tensorflow?